# How can I get thumbnails from first frame of a set of videos?

Tags: software-recommendation, windows

How can I get thumbnails from first frame of each video in a set of videos?  I am using Windows.

Comment: [Fastest way to generate video thumbnail of particulate size by FFMPEG](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35453006/3091066)

Comment: To the OP, if you're going to use the command in the link, omit the `-ss 4` part, so you'll get the first frame.

Comment: @Mulvya could you exactly tell me where and how should I type the command?

Answer (score 2):

The command to get a thumbnail from the first frame of a video is

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -vframes 1 -vf "scale=360:-1" small_thumnail.png
```

The scale filter is set to resize the image to 360 px width and choose height so that image proportion is maintained.

Comment: where should I put the command? I've never work with FFmpeg yet!

Comment: If you've never used the command prompt before, see http://www.computerhope.com/issues/chusedos.htm